# SeaDataNet's NEMO software, stuck on data validation?

Tags: oceanography, data-analysis, software

I'm new to the community and this is my first question, I would appreciate in advance your patience and your time to read this post.

I'm currently processing some oceanographic data such as salinity, oxigen concentration and conductivity, using SeaDataNet's NEMO software, version 1.6.7. I don't know if anybody has used previously NEMO, but I'll describe some basic steps in order to get to the step in which I'm stuck.

The original data file that I'm using is written in CNV format (not CSV), I provide this screenshot [image: this screenshot] and this one [image: this one] since I can't upload any data file.

This file won't work so that I've given exactly the same data but formatted in another way, this is the other one [image: this is the other one], with this data [image: with this data] The first file's header contains some information written in Spanish, since the institution for which I work is *Instituto Español de Oceanografía*. I'm using the latter file.

I'll skip right to the *data* tab, since the question might get too long and I haven't had any problem in validating every previous step.

In *data* tab, in the table below in [image: this image]  I select all necessary parameters: pressure (PRES), temperature (TEMP), conductivity (CNDC), oxigen concentration (DOX1) and salinity (PSAL). Data starts at line 35.

After that I go with pressure data: I select the first line of the pressure data (1.0 in this image) [image: this image] and then right clicking choose the *start/end* option so that NEMO stores the position of that data on that line. Units and format are automatically stored because there is already information about them on the new data file. I repeat the process with *output def.value* choosing the -999.9 value at the bottom, like this:[[image: like this [7]]

I do the same with the rest of the parameters. Now in order to validate this step, I first have to test every value and for that I choose the *update test* option, so in principle in the *test* column (next to *conversion* column) those first parameter values should appear according to the output format (*format* column).

The problem is that nothing appears in the *test* column. I've tried several times repeating the process from scratch without getting any error message when validating steps, but every time I get to the data tab, choose parameters, select the right start/end and try to update test, it continues appearing nothing. Besides, if I try anyway to validate the step, I get no error or succes message in the log tab at the bottom of the program screen. At this step the program doesn't let me change nothing else.

Am I doing something wrong though I don't get error messages? I have read several times the manual, and there is no any troubleshooting tip about this issue. Apart from that, is there any program to accomodate data so that I convert data as on image 2 to that appearing in image 4?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I really need to go on. Thank you again for your patience and for taking your time to read the whole post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having an issue with a specific software developed/mantained by a certain institution. You may be luckier in directly contacting people responsible for the software at that institution.

Please check this presentation to find relevant persons to your issue.

https://archimer.ifremer.fr/doc/00454/56547/

or contacting the official NEMO's email sdn-userdesk@seadatanet.org and/or ask about this person https://annuaire.ifremer.fr/cv/16035/en/

Finally, there is some "program to accomodate data so that I convert data as on image 2 to that appearing in image 4": what you want to do is to manipulate ascii-data, there are tons of tools.

I would use either perl or python, even notepad++ may be helpful, but it is not exactly clear what you would like to get accomplished (it is not clear which one are images 2 and 4, sorry, your post&figures are clogging us with too much information in an unclear way, try at least to crop the picture, to show only the relevant piece of information we need)

Comment: Thank you so much @Earl Grey for taking your time to read. Following your suggestion I contacted SeaDataNet's official personnel. They asked me both for the input file and saved XML model. Apparently, the problem were just some weird character on several lines of the input file that confused NEMO.

Comment: @JonAnder sometimes there are tabs instead of spaces, or different end of lines ... if you are using a computer with Microsoft Windows, I suggest installing notepad++, a very powerful and easy to use editor. Among its capabilities, it is very quick in loading and visualizing large files (disclaimer: I have no commercial interest in notepad++ ... well,to be honest  I have a negative interest because I donated some money to it :) ).